# ClassNotFoundException after instrumenting with cobertura

Tags: java, jboss, code-coverage, cobertura

Using JBoss AS 7.1.1 I want to get code coverage after testing of my project, deployed as an .war.

It seemingly works as expected until the point where I am starting the server. Here is the error message:

> 13:20:49,571 SEVERE [net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.TouchCollector] (MSC service thread 1-8) Exception when registering class: com/project/Creator: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.project.Creator from [Module "org.jboss.as.server:main" from local module loader @30c01f1c (roots: C:\Jboss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules)]
>           at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
>           at

An important part may be that without using `--auxClasspath` argument, I did get errors instrumenting this class because of dependencies. This should be fixed by the mentioned argument though.

Edit:

There are in two situations where I get problems.

During instrumentation, using the following command for instrumentation

> C:\cobertura\cobertura-2.0.3\cobertura-instrument.bat" --basedir C:\Jboss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments project.war --datafile C:\Jboss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\cobertura.ser --auxClasspath ""C:\workspace\jboss-build\src\com\arbitrage\j2ee\common\dto\TypeData.java

which gives me the error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.arbitrage.j2ee.common.dto.TypeData
>       at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaClassWriter.getCommonSuperClass(CoberturaClassWriter.java:35)

But, when I start up JBoss, it does so without giving any errors.

However, when I stop JBoss I get this error:

> ERROR [stderr] Exception in thread "Thread-45" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sourceforge/cobertura/coveragedata/TouchCollector$ApplyToClassDataLightClassmapListener

In the second case instrumentation goes well with the following command

> C:\cobertura\cobertura-2.0.3\cobertura-instrument.bat" addInstrumentationToArchive C:\Jboss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments\screator.war --includeClasses "com.project.*" --datafile C:\Jboss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\cobertura.ser --auxClasspath "C:.m2\repository\com\project\1\project-1.jar

Which gives me an OK

> INFO: Cobertura: Saved information on 41 classes.

Now the problem occurs when starting up JBoss

> SEVERE net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.TouchCollector Exception when registering class: com/project/Creator: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.project.Creator from [Module "org.jboss.as.server:main" from local module loader @30c01f1 (roots: C:\Jboss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules)].

etc etc.

I have added `-Djboss.shutdown.forceHalt=false` to the VM arguments.

Help is much appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding Cobertura (and its transitive dependencies) to the CP of your container (e.g., `lib/ext` in Tomcat)?

Comment: Thanks for the interest. I added cobertura to my maven config, so it gets deployed now. But still I am facing problems starting up JBoss. Please see the edit.